# Async-CTP Installation fails

Tags: async-ctp

I have already uninstalled KB2635973, KB2549864 and didn't have KB2615527.
Still I get this error:

```
Patch (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Async-CTP-v3\VS10-KB0000001.msp) Install failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU). Msi Log: 
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:03:15).
```

Comment: You're probably better off using VS11 beta.

Comment: Thanks, but VS11 is not compatible with Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by uninstalling KB2645410